# how to specify DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH using buildbot?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, buildbot

I am building and runing test for my project using buildbot. I am using mac as slave. The problem arises when I try to run the test because it cannot find the dynamic library which is shaved in different directory.

From the buildbot tutorial I can see a varibale called [env](http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.2/Using-ShellCommands.html#Using-ShellCommands). It uses PATH so I supposed DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH would also work the same way so I did

```
  env  =   {"DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH":["/x/y/lib","/x1/y1/lib","${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}"]}
```

but it still cannot find the shared library that I want those binary to find. can anyone help me on this one.pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was kind of right.
This is the way to do but you should do in

```
BuilderConfig ( ..,..,..,env = {'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH':'/x/y/lib:x1/y1/lib'}
```

and thats it